# c# input only using slot 0

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to get a user to input 1 value into the array, and then exit to main menu, then the next person to enter a value gets his put into the next bracket, not replace slot 0, currently it just loops the first array bracket and replaces the number. Help would be much appreciated

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] myArray = new int[10];

    while (true)
    {
        int enteredNumber;

        Startmenu();
        enteredNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (enteredNumber == 1)
        {                    
            for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Insert Number:");
                myArray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("blabla");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.Clear();
        }

        if (enteredNumber == 9)
        {
            if (Login(1234, 3) == true)
            {
                foreach (int number in myArray)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(number);
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: At the end of your `for` loop, you should have 10 items in your array (assuming `enteredNumber == 1`) - try setting a breakpoint on the first `Console.Clear()` line and examing `myArray` in the debugger. But then you overwrite the array on each iteration of the `while` loop. It appears you may be trying to do too much in one method..? Consider breaking out different pieces of functionality into separate methods.

Comment: But the main thing is, you need to add a `Console.ReadKey()` after displaying the array items so the user has a chance to actually see them before the `while` loop starts over again.

Comment: Also, to answer your main question, you would need to not populate the array in a loop, and instead somehow keep track of which index should be populated next. Then, each time through the loop, you populate that item and increment the variable tracking the next index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem I think you have in that code is that you're trying to do too much in one method. You might want to break out discreet operations into separate methods, which will both enable code reuse and also serve to make your code more readable.

First, you need a method that will get an `int` from the user. Let's write a helper method that does that, which takes in a `string` that will be displayed as a prompt to the user, and which will continue to prompt them until they enter a valid `int`. We can use `int.TryParse` to determine if they enter a valie `int`. It takes a `string` argument to parse, and an `out int` that will contain the parsed value if it succeeds. The method itself returns `true` if it was successful:

```
private static int GetIntFromUser(string prompt)
{
    int result;

    do
    {
        Console.Write(prompt);
    } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result));

    return result;
}
```

You don't show the code for `ShowMenu`, but it probably gives the user some menu choices, and I've added the functionality where it returns the menu choice entered by the user:

```
private static int ShowMenu()
{
    int menuChoice;

    do
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Main Menu:");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Input an array item");
        Console.WriteLine("9. Print the numbers\n");
        menuChoice = GetIntFromUser("Enter your choice (1 or 9): ");
    } while (menuChoice != 1 && menuChoice != 9);

    return menuChoice;
}
```

Now, another thing you seem to be missing that might help here, is to add a "pause" to the program after printing out the array items, so the user has a chance to see them. I think this is probably the main problem. Currently you write them all out to the screen, then the `while` loop runs again and you don't get a chance to see it. Here's a helper method that asks the user to press a key when they're ready, and then waits for the user to press a key:

```
private static void WaitForUserInput()
{
    Console.Write("\nPress any key to continue...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

We can also put the code to populate the array in a separate method. Since you want to enable the user to populate only one item at a time, we will need to keep track of which item is the next one to populate, so we'll set a class-level variable for that, and make use of it in the method. We'll populate that item, then increment the variable. Of course we have to first make sure the next item is not greater than the number of items available:

```
private static int NextIndexToPopulate = 0;

private static void PopulateNextArrayItem(int[] array)
{
    if (array == null) return;

    if (NextIndexToPopulate >= array.Length) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The array is full; no items left to enter.");
        WaitForUserInput();
    }
    else
    {
        array[NextIndexToPopulate] = GetIntFromUser("Enter number to insert: ");
        NextIndexToPopulate++;
    }
}
```

And another method can be used to print out the array:

```
private static void PrintArray(int[] array)
{
    if (array == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The array is null - nothing to print.");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here are the array items entered:");

        for (int i = 0; i < NextIndexToPopulate; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

You also didn't show the `Login` code, so here's a dummy method I'll use that always returns true:

```
private static bool Login(int first, int second)
{
    return true;
}
```

Now, with all that extra stuff encapsulated in methods, our main code becomes a little more readable, there's less chance for errors, and when there are errors, it's more clear what they are:

```
private static void Main()
{
    int[] myArray = new int[10];

    while (true)
    {
        int enteredNumber = ShowMenu();

        if (enteredNumber == 1)
        {
            PopulateNextArrayItem(myArray);
        }
        else if (enteredNumber == 9)
        {
            if (Login(1234, 3))
            {
                PrintArray(myArray);
                WaitForUserInput();
            }
        }
    }
}
```